# Как удалить все отличные от цифр символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день! Подскажите, каким образом можно написать регулярное выражение, которое способно найти в строчке "1 200руб" только цифры? До этого с регулярными выражениями дел не имел. (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для javascript код будет таким:
сумма="1 200руб".replace(/D+/g,"")

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы удалить из строки все нецифровые символы, используйте регулярное выражение `[^0-9]+` (в большинстве случаев, сработает и `\D+`), а в качестве замены используйте пустую строку. `[^0-9]` (синоним `\D`) — это исключающий символьный класс, образованный с помощью `[^` и `]`, который находит любые символы кроме указанных внутри класса. Т.е. `0-9` указывает на диапазон символов таблицы Юникод от 0 до 9, т.е. все цифры ASCII. Квантификатор `+` находит 1 и более последовательностей символов, указанных в квантифицируемом шаблоне.

- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23): `var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"\D+", "", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);` ([демо](https://ideone.com/jXMOBk))
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript): `var res = s.replace(/\D+/g, "");` ([демо](http://jsfiddle.net/p5kb6g4p/))
- [java](/questions/tagged/java): `String res = s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");` ([демо](https://ideone.com/04tOQG))
- [php](/questions/tagged/php): `$res = preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $s);` ([демо](https://ideone.com/aqc0vO))
- [python](/questions/tagged/python): `res = re.sub(r"\D+", "", s)` ([демо](https://ideone.com/hfxgpl)) (в Python 3 добавьте `flags=re.A` для отсева Юникод-цифр)
- [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby): `res = s.gsub(/\D+/, "")` ([демо](https://ideone.com/x8bbfo))
- [r](/questions/tagged/r): `res <- gsub("\\D+", "", x)` ([демо](https://ideone.com/yaEbII))
- [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell): `$res = s -replace '[^0-9]+', ""`
- [scala](/questions/tagged/scala): `val res = s.replaceAll("""\D+""", "")` ([демо](https://ideone.com/qaGMqj))
- [perl](/questions/tagged/perl): `s/\D+//g` ([демо](https://ideone.com/gTqecm))
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): `std::regex reg(R"(\D+)"); std::cout<<std::regex_replace(s, reg, "");` ([демо](https://ideone.com/XE8stY))
- [go](/questions/tagged/go): `` s = regexp.MustCompile(`\D+`).ReplaceAllString(s, "") ``  ([демо](https://play.golang.org/p/6mBHRs7JxG))
- [sed](/questions/tagged/sed): `sed 's/[^0-9][^0-9]*//g'`  ([демо](https://ideone.com/UUfVRZ))
- [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c): `NSError *error = nil; NSString *myText = @"abc 123 x";   NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^0-9]+" options:nil error:&error]; NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myText length]) withTemplate:@""];`  ([демо](https://ideone.com/69vHn2))
- [swift](/questions/tagged/swift): `let res = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^0-9]+", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)`
- [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl): `regsub -all {\D+} $s "" res`  ([демо](https://ideone.com/TqtMz9))
- [lua](/questions/tagged/lua): `res = s:gsub("%D+", "")`  ([демо](https://ideone.com/1cqFBq))
- [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin): `var res = "abc 123 t".replace("""\D+""".toRegex(), "")`  ([демо](http://rextester.com/POMMP47519))
- [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy): `def res = s.replaceAll(/\D+/, "")`  ([демо](https://ideone.com/AzI2Kt))

Answer (score 1):

Для Java кусок кода будет выглядеть так

```
private static final String NUMBER = "([0-9]+)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(NUMBER);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(externalText);//указываем свой текст
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

ключевые классы Pattern и Matcher в javadoc'e

Comment: если между цифрами есть пробелы, используйте более хитрое ([0-9]+)([][0-9]+)*

Answer (score -1):

Укажите язык. Например, в ruby -

```
/[0-9]/
```